# Join a list<object> with multiple tables in linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

i have a problem whith join a list<> on tables of linq to sql,

listaFcbm is a List is a table of Fcbm and entLogCancelacionAcreditacion is complex object

```
var listaFcbm = new Fcbm_Methods().ObtenAcreditacionesEliminadasLog(inicio, fin);

using (FrCEntities db = new FrCEntities())
{
    var lista = (from a in db.FrCs
                 join b in listaFcbm on a.FrCs_Name equals b.Fcbm_Name
                 join c in db.HIS_MOVS on b.Fcbm_Mov_Id equals c.Mov_Id
                 where b.Fcbm_Mov == 1 && a.FrCs_Actv == 1
                 select new entLogCancelacionAcreditacion
                 {
                     No_Socio = a.FrCs_Name,
                     NombreCompleto = a.FrCs_Fst_Name + " " + a.FrCs_Mdl_Name + " " + a.FrCs_Lst_Name,
                     Hotel = c.prop_code,
                     Reservacion = c.rsrv_code,
                     Puntos = b.Fcbm_Points,
                     FechaEntrada = b.Fcbm_Checkin,
                     FechaSalida = b.Fcbm_Checkout,
                     Usuario = b.Fcbm_Add_Usr,
                     TipoAcreditacion = b.Fcbm_Code
                 }).ToList();

    return lista;
}
```

and the error is

```
Unable to create a constant value of type ' BLCityPremios.Fcbm ' . Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context .
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I would lose the upfront join to listaFcbm and only join it in afterwards on the results from the DB call.

Comment: since i don't find any `BLCityPremios.Fcbm`in your code, i'd look in the constructor of `entLogCancelacionAcreditacion`

Comment: thanks for responding , as I get the same result using listafcbm like the FCBM table?